# Python - how do I force the use of a factory method to instantiate an object?

Tags: python, class-factory

I have a set of related classes that all inherit from one base class.  I would like to use a factory method to instantiate objects for these classes. I want to do this because then I can store the objects in a dictionary keyed by the class name before returning the object to the caller.  Then if there is a request for an object of a particular class, I can check to see whether one already exists in my dictionary.  If not, I'll instantiate it and add it to the dictionary.  If so, then I'll return the existing object from the dictionary.  This will essentially turn all the classes in my module into singletons.

I want to do this because the base class that they all inherit from does some automatic wrapping of the functions in the subclasses, and I don't want to the functions to get wrapped more than once, which is what happens currently if two objects of the same class are created.

The only way I can think of doing this is to check the stacktrace in the `__init__()` method of the base class, which will always be called, and to throw an exception if the stacktrace does not show that the request to make the object is coming from the factory function.

Is this a good idea?

**Edit:** Here is the source code for my base class.  I've been told that I need to figure out metaclasses to accomplish this more elegantly, but this is what I have for now.  All Page objects use the same Selenium Webdriver instance, which is in the driver module imported at the top.  This driver is very expensive to initialize -- it is initialized the first time a LoginPage is created.  After it is initialized the `initialize()` method will return the existing driver instead of creating a new one.  The idea is that the user must begin by creating a LoginPage.  There will eventually be dozens of Page classes defined and they will be used by unit testing code to verify that the behavior of a website is correct.

```
from driver import get_driver, urlpath, initialize
from settings import urlpaths

class DriverPageMismatchException(Exception):
    pass

class URLVerifyingPage(object):
    # we add logic in __init__() to check the expected urlpath for the page
    # against the urlpath that the driver is showing - we only want the page's
    # methods to be invokable if the driver is actualy at the appropriate page.
    # If the driver shows a different urlpath than the page is supposed to
    # have, the method should throw a DriverPageMismatchException

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = get_driver()
        self._adjust_methods(self.__class__)

    def _adjust_methods(self, cls):
        for attr, val in cls.__dict__.iteritems():
            if callable(val) and not attr.startswith("_"):
                print "adjusting:"+str(attr)+" - "+str(val)
                setattr(
                    cls,
                    attr,
                    self._add_wrapper_to_confirm_page_matches_driver(val)
                )
        for base in cls.__bases__:
            if base.__name__ == 'URLVerifyingPage': break
            self._adjust_methods(base)

    def _add_wrapper_to_confirm_page_matches_driver(self, page_method):
        def _wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if urlpath() != urlpaths[self.__class__.__name__]:
                raise DriverPageMismatchException(
                    "path is '"+urlpath()+
                    "' but '"+urlpaths[self.__class.__name__]+"' expected "+
                    "for "+self.__class.__name__
                )
            return page_method(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return _wrapper


class LoginPage(URLVerifyingPage):
    def __init__(self, username=username, password=password, baseurl="http://example.com/"):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.driver = initialize(baseurl)
        super(LoginPage, self).__init__()

    def login(self):
        driver.find_element_by_id("username").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys(self.username)
        driver.find_element_by_id("password").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys(self.password)
        driver.find_element_by_id("login_button").click()
        return HomePage()

class HomePage(URLVerifyingPage):
    def some_method(self):
        ...
        return SomePage()

    def many_more_methods(self):
        ...
        return ManyMorePages()
```

It's no big deal if a page gets instantiated a handful of times -- the methods will just get wrapped a handful of times and a handful of unnecessary checks will take place, but everything will still work.  But it would be bad if a page was instantiated dozens or hundreds or tens of thousands of times.  I could just put a flag in the class definition for each page and check to see if the methods have already been wrapped, but I like the idea of keeping the class definitions pure and clean and shoving all the hocus-pocus into a deep corner of my system where no one can see it and it just works.

Comment: Are you after an instance factory or a class factory? Have you tried a relatively simple class decorator approach? (Can we see what you've tried that doesn't work for instance?)

Comment: Let me get this straight. You want to turn all your classes into singletons because their base class is broken? Sounds like shooting your dog because a crazy bum who keeps breaking into your house is allergic to dogs. IOW an entirely misguided "solution". You sure you don't want to fix the base class, or at least work around its flaw?

Comment: @delnan I think the clue is in the title: "How do I **force**..." - emphasis mine

Comment: @JonClements That part, as the entire question, is about implementing the "solution" of making all classes singletons. I'm questioning whether that is a sane solution.

Comment: @delnan I am not disagreeing - I generally find if you try to "force" something - somethings gone wrong at a more fundamental level (so consider me in agreement - as that was the tone of my comment)

Comment: +1 to @delnan. I think the OP's actual problem here is that there's some "automatic wrapping" that's done at `__init__` time and can only be done once per class. This sounds like a serious bug or design flaw, and it would be better to fix it than to come up with a complicated workaround.

Comment: I've edited my original question to explain more about what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: @JonCrowell: What version of Python are you using? Especially given that you're looking into metaclasses, it makes a big difference whether you're using 2.6-7, 3.2, or 3.3. (Hopefully you're not using an older 2.x or 3.x.)

Comment: My code has to run on 2.6.

Answer (score 3):

In Python, it's almost never worth trying to "force" anything. Whatever you come up with, someone can get around it by monkeypatching your class, copying and editing the source, fooling around with bytecode, etc.

So, just write your factory, and document that as the right way to get an instance of your class, and expect anyone who writes code using your classes to understand TOOWTDI, and not violate it unless she really knows what she's doing and is willing to figure out and deal with the consequences.

If you're just trying to prevent accidents, rather than intentional "misuse", that's a different story. In fact, it's just standard design-by-contract: check the invariant. Of course at this point, `SillyBaseClass` is already screwed up, and it's too late to repair it, and all you can do is `assert`, `raise`, `log`, or whatever else is appropriate. But that's what you want: it's a logic error in the application, and the only thing to do is get the programmer to fix it, so `assert` is probably exactly what you want.

So:

```
class SillyBaseClass:
    singletons = {}

class Foo(SillyBaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        assert self.__class__ not in SillyBaseClass.singletons

def get_foo():
    if Foo not in SillyBaseClass.singletons:
        SillyBaseClass.singletons[Foo] = Foo()
    return SillyBaseClass.singletons[Foo]
```

If you really do want to stop things from getting this far, you *can* check the invariant earlier, in the `__new__` method, but unless "`SillyBaseClass` got screwed up" is equivalent to "launch the nukes", why bother?

Comment: Well, my silly base class is not the far along -- I still have time to change my design.  See the edit to my original question above. I am trying to avoid mistakes (such as the class being instantiated hundreds of times in a loop) rather than intentional misuse.

Answer (score 2):

it sounds like you want to provide a `__new__` implementation:  Something like:

```
class MySingledtonBase(object):
    instance_cache = {}
    def __new__(cls, arg1, arg2):
        if cls in MySingletonBase.instance_cache:
            return MySingletonBase.instance_cache[cls]
        self = super(MySingletonBase, cls).__new__(arg1, arg2)
        MySingletonBase.instance_cache[cls] = self
        return self
```

Comment: This shows how to avoid an explicit factory method in the first place, not how to enforce the use of an explicit factory method. It could conceivably turn out to be what the OP would actually wants, if he rethought his problem, but without any argument for that, it's just answering a different and only vaguely-related problem.

Comment: Ahh.. hmm.. yes... the factory methods could, if Jon *really wanted*, call `__new__` with some special, magic, secret arguments, which `__new__` verifies are present.  it could be something unreasonably unlikely to pass accidentally (like, a guid), or just useful, but verbose, arguments that tell `__new__` what it needs to do.

Comment: If you want to go that far, it's easier to make it something _impossible_ to pass accidentally, like an `object()` instance that's only available from within the scope where the base class and the `__new__` method are created… But of course, as you strongly imply, you almost certainly _don't_ want to go that far.

Comment: I like this -- avoiding an explicit factory method is even better if I can get the base class to do all the work magically. I've edited my original question above and added code and details.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than adding complex code to catch mistakes at runtime, I'd first try to use convention to guide users of your module to do the right thing on their own.

Give your classes "private" names (prefixed by an underscore), give them names that suggest they shouldn't be instantiated (eg _Internal...) and make your factory function "public".

That is, something like this:

```
class _InternalSubClassOne(_BaseClass):
    ...

class _InternalSubClassTwo(_BaseClass):
    ...

# An example factory function.
def new_object(arg):
    return _InternalSubClassOne() if arg == 'one' else _InternalSubClassTwo()
```

I'd also add docstrings or comments to each class, like "Don't instantiate this class by hand, use the factory method `new_object`."

Answer (score 0):

You can also just nest classes in factory method, as described here:
https://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Factory.html#preventing-direct-creation

Working example from mentioned source:

```
# Factory/shapefact1/NestedShapeFactory.py
import random

class Shape(object):
    types = []

def factory(type):
    class Circle(Shape):
        def draw(self): print("Circle.draw")
        def erase(self): print("Circle.erase")

    class Square(Shape):
        def draw(self): print("Square.draw")
        def erase(self): print("Square.erase")

    if type == "Circle": return Circle()
    if type == "Square": return Square()
    assert 0, "Bad shape creation: " + type

def shapeNameGen(n):
    for i in range(n):
        yield factory(random.choice(["Circle", "Square"]))

# Circle() # Not defined

for shape in shapeNameGen(7):
    shape.draw()
    shape.erase()
```

I'm not fan of this solution, just want to add this as one more option.